# How to get selected object data?

Tags: mapinfo, fields-attributes, mapbasic

I want to get attributes from object what was selected on map. I understand how to get selected object:

```
Dim nrecords as Ineger
Dim obj as Object
nRecords = SelectionInfo(SEL_INFO_NROWS)
For i = 1 To nRecords
   Fetch rec i From selection
   obj = selection.obj
```

Now i want to get any attributes from this object. How can i do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it by looping over the columns in the table and writing the values to two arrays: One for the column name and one for the value.

```
Dim sQuery, arrColNames(), arrColValues() As String
Dim nCount, nNumCols, nCol As Integer
Dim aCol As Alias
Dim oSel As Object

'**Getting the name of the query (instead of Selection)
sQuery = SelectionInfo(SEL_INFO_SELNAME)

'**Get the number of columns and making space for these in the arrays
nNumCols = TableInfo(sQuery, TAB_INFO_NCOLS)
ReDim arrColNames(nNumCols)
ReDim arrColValues(nNumCols)

Fetch First From sQuery
Do Until EOT(sQuery)
   aCol = sQuery & ".OBJ"
   oSel = aCol

   '**Looping thru the columns
   For nCol = 1 To nNumCols
      arrColNames(nCol) = ColumnInfo(sQuery, "COL" & nCol, COL_INFO_NAME)
      aCol = sQuery & ".COL" & nCol
      arrColValues(nCol) = aCol
   Next

   '**Here you will do some stuff with the object and the column values
   '...

   Fetch Next From sQuery
Loop
```

Note that I'm using a Do Until loop as that's better for dealing with deleted records in a table.

Comment: Sory taht do not accepting answer for a long time. Solution works nice. But i was pretty suprised that for getting objects's attributes i gonna iterate through whole table.

Comment: You aren't looping thru the entire table, only thru the selected records. If you know there will only be one selected record, you can remove the outer loop: Do Until EOT() ... Loop and only keep the inner loop on the columns

Answer (score 0):

If you nedd to special attribute you can access by Selection.NameOfAttribute

Comment: Could you elaborate, please?

Comment: For example if you have attribute "Name" in you layer you can get value from selected object by Selection.Name

Comment: Thanks, please add this comment as an edit in your answer.